# Can someone please help me figure out how many local maxima, minima and saddle points there are on this surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, maxima-minima

[image]

The image shows the side, top and bottom view of a surface. Please feel free to inquire more about the images down below in the comments!

**Question: How many relative maxima, relative minima and saddle points are in this surface?**

I have input 4, 5 and 4 respectively but atleast one of them is wrong and I do not know which. Could someone please help me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: I only see 1 local minima (at $(x,y) \approx (0,0)$)

Comment: It's hard to tell just from the pictures (do you have a formula for the function) but it **looks** to me like there are 4 maxima at the corners, 1 minimum (in the middle) and 4 saddlepoints (in the centers of the sides).

Comment: ^thats the answer! thank you! I understand how you got the saddle points and maxima but aren't there minima on the side views as well? I am confused

Comment: @kazi This depends on whether the function is constrained to be within in the depicted domain ($[-2,2]^2$) or considered over all of $\mathbb R^2$. I'd have asked for clarification if only given these pictures.

NB in that case you also have a lot more maxima - 2 per side and the 4 in the interior for a total of 12 and 9 minima (each corner, 1 per side and the interior). Only the number of saddles remains at 4.